# Is it possible to create a generic CRUD in JavaFX

Tags: java, generics, javafx, generic-interface

I am developing a JavaFx Application and I have to use CRUD for several model classes. I want to create a generic interface and then would like to implement for those classes. I couldn't find any example where it is Implemented with JavaFX. I am not using DAO or Hibernate it is just JDBC connection.

What I have done so far

```
public interface CrudInterface<T, PK extends Serializable> {
    void create(T t);
    T read(PK id);
    void update(T t);
    void delete(T t);
    ObservableList<T> getAll();
}
```

Implementation:

```
    public class ProductImplementation implements CrudInterface, ProductInterface{

    //Other Methods
.
.
.
        @Override
            public void create(Product product) {
                try {
                    DatabaseConnection localConnection = new DatabaseConnection();
                    connection = localConnection.getLocalConnection();
                    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                    String query = "INSERT INTO products (product_name, bar_code, product_size, product_cost, product_net_dealer_price, productQuantity, product_alert_quantity, product_tax, product_image, product_invoice_detail, product_category_id, product_subcategory_id, suplier_name) VALUES  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, product.getName());
                    preparedStatement.setString(2, product.getBarcode());
                    preparedStatement.setString(3, product.getSize());
                    preparedStatement.setInt(4, product.getPrice());
                    preparedStatement.setString(5, product.getNetDealerPrice());
                    preparedStatement.setInt(6, product.getQuantity());
                    preparedStatement.setInt(7, product.getAlertQuantity());
                    preparedStatement.setInt(8, product.getTax());
                    preparedStatement.setString(9, product.getImage());
                    preparedStatement.setString(10, product.getProductInvoiceDetail());
        //            preparedStatement.setInt(11, product.getCategories().getCategoryID());
        //            preparedStatement.setInt(12, product.getSubCategories().getSubCategoryID());
        //            preparedStatement.setInt(13, product.getSuppliers().getSupplierID());
                    preparedStatement.execute();
                    connection.commit();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    try {
                        connection.rollback();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ProductImplementation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    Logger.getLogger(ProductImplementation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                } finally {
                    try {
                        connection.close();
                        preparedStatement.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ProductImplementation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am stuck and unable to pass the object of model class to create data. Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

**Edited**
Signature of my create method in CRUD Interface is

```
void create(T t);
```

Now I need to replace `T` with my model class while Implementing the interface.
i.e. `Product`, `Category`, `SubCategory` etc.

I have several Classes with the CRUD and I do not want to repeat these methods in each of the Java Class separately therefor I need to create a **Generic Interface**.

Comment: What do you mean "pass the object of model class"? Is that the `Product`?

Comment: Yes, it is product which has all the data to insert would be passed from a controller.

Comment: So the `create` method gets `null` as `product` ?

Comment: When I replace `Object` with the `Product`
It say **method does not override or implement a method from a supertype**

Comment: @IvanKukic could you please have a look into this.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to do and where are you stuck. Try to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54881173/edit) and clarify

Comment: @c0der I have edited my question please have a look.

Comment: you are only implementing CrudInterface, you are not defining any type information. I would expect something in the form of `implements CrudInterface<Product, Integer>` or whatever type you use for your primary key.

Comment: @Gimby thanks it worked and after seeing your reply I realized sometimes we do silly mistakes.